# Javascript onclick on children

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

I've got a weird problem in Internet Explorer. Attaching a click event to the children of an element when the parent already has a click event doesn't seem to work.

I've got the following code so far:

```
<span>Some text 
    <strong class="opts">
        <a href="#opt-action" rel="opt-data">Opt name</a>
    </strong>
</span>
```

I'm attaching the click event listener with the following code(where `el` is the `span`):

```
el.onclick = function()
{
    ..
}

var optWrapper = el.firstChild.nextSibling,
    opts = optWrapper.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    numOpts = opts.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numOpts; i++)
{
    var opt = opts[i],
        f =  null;

    switch (opt.getAttribute('href').split('#', 2)[1])
    {
        case '#opt-action':
            f = someFunction;
            break;
    }

    if (f !== null)
        opt.onclick = f;
}
```

And `someFunction` makes a call to `stopEvent`, which is defined as:

```
var stopEvent = function(e)
{
    e  = e || event;

    // Stop bubbling
    if (e.stopPropagation)
        e.stopPropagation();
    else
        e.cancelBubble  = true;

    // Prevent the default action
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else
        e.returnValue = false;
}
```

and `someFunction` returns `false` at the end.

Any suggestions what could be causing the event to **not** fire on the children?

**EDIT:**

As noted by [@Kevin Babcock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815595/javascript-onclick-on-children/5816124#5816124) the `firstChild` was indeed one of my problems, the second problem was that the `href` attribute in IE is different from retrieving the `href` in Firefox or Google Chrome.

If I call `getAttribute('href')` in IE I get an **absolute** url and in Firefox and Google Chrome I get a **relative** url. I've updated the code to split the `href` on the `#`.

The code shown above is dynamically loaded. After the load has completed any javascript found in the data is executed, I **think** my problem is that the script **isn't loaded by IE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
var optWrapper = el.firstChild
```

Because your `<span>` element is immediately followed by "Some text" the result of calling `firstChild()` on it will be a `TextNode` element. Subsequently, `getElementsByTagName()` is undefined on a `TextNode` element.

Instead, do this:

```
var opts = el.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    numOpts = opts.length;
```

Here's the full source that you can drop in your page to get the results you are after:

```
(function(){
    var stopEvent = function(e) {
        console.log("stopEvent called");
        e  = e || event;

        // Stop bubbling
        if (e.stopPropagation)
            e.stopPropagation();
        else
            e.cancelBubble  = true;

        // Prevent the default action
        if (e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        else
            e.returnValue = false;
    }

    var someFunction = function(e) {
        console.log("someFunction called");
        stopEvent(e);
    };

    var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    span.onclick = function() {
        console.log("span clicked");
    };

    var opts = span.getElementsByTagName("a"),
        numOpts = opts.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < numOpts; i++) {
        var opt = opts[i],
            f =  null;

        switch (opt.getAttribute('href')) {
            case '#opt-action':
                f = someFunction;
                break;
        }

        if (f !== null)
            opt.onclick = f;
    }
})();
```

Comment: your answer was indeed one of my problems, I've updated my answer.